# Coefficients in Cox model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, cox-model

The output of `coxph` has coefficients vector as follows:

```
tenure   function_sendTAX   function_sendAUDIT   function_sendFAS   hierarchy 
8.90             NA               -0.6154            1.39                -.55
```

I have just 3 covariates: `tenure`, `function_send`, and `hierarchy`. But I really do not know why the function_send appears like this, with its levels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One value is collinear or constant. `function_send` is categorical with at least four levels `AUDIT` and `FAS`. Typically, `model.matrix` generates a covariate matrix for factors using dummy encoding, but first it uses `droplevels` to exclude redundant or unused factor levels, and only after complete case exclusion. That means that the level `TAX` is most likely collinear with another feature.

Including the following output would be helpful: `table(function_send)`.

`coxph` does not have an intercept term because the baseline hazard function *is* the intercept, and it is not estimated by default.

**How to handle this situation**

1. The data structure needs to be rearranged to be accurate for the model and the question.
2. The "accidental" multicollinearity needs to be described.

1 is the most common scenario. This is a result of either including variables into a model all higgledy piggledy or because two variables really summarize the same thing. Using a bare minimum of background on the problem, it seems that one of the two other variables may be binary (1/0), most likely not tenure unless you have dichotomized that (many reasons not to do this). Hierarchy is another likely culprit: check if hierarchy is collinear with function by using the `table` command. If there is a whole row of 0s except 1 1, these values are collinear. Choose one to drop, most likely hierarchy for the consistency of function. Very small n can exacerbate these kinds of problems.

2 is less common, the right model with sufficient sample size and a well designed model rarely results in accidental collinearity, but it may happen. In which case, describe the results as is. What I have done in the past is summarize the results and put a blank cell for the coefficient to "sendTAX" (which you should recode to a readable format when summarizing results), add a footnote and note that the model coefficient was unavailable due to collinearity.

R pragmatically chooses a "parametrization" of the model that drops redundant variables. The interpretation of the output and predictions is all correct and cogent. If it's true accidental collinearity (case 2) just report as-is.

Comment: @Mori it seems that AdamO has identified your problem better than I did. There is some problem with the way that your data are structured so that the `TAX` level of `function_send` has data collinear with the other levels or in some way with the other predictors. Editing your question to provide the `table(function_send)` output as AdamO suggests, and the full form of your call to `coxph()`, would help.

Answer (score 1):

Although you might think of `function_send` as a single categorical covariate, it has three different levels that must be considered separately in Cox regression, or any regression for that matter. In this case the level `TAX` is taken as the reference level, and the values for the `AUDIT` and `FAS` levels represent the differences of each of those from that reference level.

EDIT: as a comment notes that this is from `coxph()` in R, the issue with the `NA` for the `TAX` level of `function_send` is presumably collinearity, as @AdamO suggests. When that problem is addressed, however, there still will necessarily be a coefficient for each level of that categorical covariate, representing its difference from the reference level.

Comment: Not quite, I'm not sure how the `coef` vector was displayed here, but R by default drops the referent level from a factor variable when displaying regression output.

Comment: @AdamO thought about that, but this doesn't look like R output to me. Can't rule out that some other software might represent the reference level with a coefficient `NA`.

Comment: Thanks Edm for your response.  Could you please let me know how I can solve this problem. Since I do not know that much a bout coxph model.

Comment: It is indeed the R output EdM.

Comment: Thanks Adam0 for your responce. As I mentioned this topic is new to me can you lead me how I can solve this issue. That is what should i do.

Comment: @Mori edit applied to my answer to address ths